# Boolean operators vs Bitwise operators

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, boolean-operations

I am confused as to when I should use Boolean vs bitwise operators

- `and` vs `&`
- `or` vs `|`

Could someone enlighten me as to when do i use each and when will using one over the other affect my results?

Comment: Note that the answers you'll get roughly apply to about all other (mainstream imperative) languages as well.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Here are a couple of guidelines:

- Boolean operators are usually used on *boolean* values but bitwise operators are usually used on *integer* values.
- Boolean operators are *short-circuiting* but bitwise operators are *not* short-circuiting.

The short-circuiting behaviour is useful in expressions like this:

```
if x is not None and x.foo == 42:
    # ...
```

This would not work correctly with the bitwise `&` operator because both sides would always be evaluated, giving `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo'`. When you use the boolean `and`operator the second expression is not evaluated when the first is False. Similarly `or` does not evaluate the second argument if the first is True.

Comment: Supplementary: In Python `&`, `|`, `^` are set operations too.

Comment: Additional supplementary: in Python, bit-wise will not allow mixed types, but boolean will. e.g. `True or "True"` is fine (it will return the first truthy value), but `True | "True"` will throw an exception.

Comment: @Hannele That has nothing to do with mixed types. Bitwise operations only make sense with integers and any other type will throw an exception. The point here is that Python treats False and True as 0 and 1 respectively: `0 == False` and `1 == True` are both true.

Comment: @NunoAndré True enough, that is a more accurate explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

Here's a further difference, which had me puzzled for a while just now: because `&` (and other bitwise operators) have a higher precedence than `and` (and other boolean operators) the following expressions evaluate to different values:

```
0 < 1 & 0 < 2
```

versus

```
0 < 1 and 0 < 2
```

To wit, the first yields `False` as it is equivalent to `0 < (1 & 0) < 2`, hence `0 < 0 < 2`, hence `0 < 0 and 0 < 2`.

Answer (score 28):

In theory, `and` and `or` come straight from boolean logic (and therefore operate on two booleans to produce a boolean), while `&` and `|` apply the boolean and/or to the individual bits of integers. There are a lot lot of questions here on how the latter work exactly.

Here are practical differences that potentially affect your results:

1. `and` and `or` short-circuiting, e.g. `True or sys.exit(1)` will not exit, because for a certain value of the first operand (`True or ...`, `False and ...`), the second one wouldn't change the result so does not need to be evaluated. But `|` and `&` don't short-circuit - `True | sys.exit(1)` throws you outta the REPL.
2. `&` and `|` are regular operators and can be overloaded, while `and` and `or` are forged into the language (although the special method for coercion to boolean may have side effects).

   - This also applies to some other languages with operator overloading
3. `and` and `or` return the value of an operand instead of `True` or `False`. This doesn't change the meaning of boolean expressions in conditions -  `1 or True` is `1`, but `1` is true, too. But it was once used to emulate a conditional operator (`cond ? true_val : false_val` in C syntax, `true_val if cond else false_val` in Python). For `&` and `|`, the result type depends on how the operands overload the respective special methods (`True & False` is `False`, `99 & 7` is `3`, for sets it's unions/intersection...).

   - This also applies to some other languages like Ruby, Perl and Javascript

But even when e.g. `a_boolean & another_boolean` would work identically, the right solution is using `and` - simply because `and` and `or` are associated with boolean expression and condition while `&` and `|` stand for bit twiddling.

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to do element-wise boolean operations in `numpy`, the answer is somewhat different.  You can use `&` and `|` for element-wise boolean operations, but `and` and `or` will return value error.

To be on the safe side, you can use the [numpy logic functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html).

```
np.array([True, False, True]) | np.array([True, False, False])
# array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

np.array([True, False, True]) or np.array([True, False, False])
# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

np.logical_or(np.array([True, False, True]), np.array([True, False, False]))
# array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 4):

The general rule is to use the appropriate operator for the existing operands. Use ***boolean*** (logical) operators with ***boolean*** operands, and ***bitwise*** operators with (wider) ***integral*** operands (note: *False* is equivalent to ***0***, and *True* to ***1***). The only "tricky" scenario is applying boolean operators to non boolean operands.
Let's take a simple example: `5 & 7` *vs.* `5 and 7`.

For the *bitwise **and*** (**&**), things are pretty straightforward:

> ```
> 5     = 0b101
> 7     = 0b111
> -----------------
> 5 & 7 = 0b101 = 5 (= 7 & 5)
> ```

For the *logical **and***, here's what [[Python.Docs]: Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) states (**emphasis** is mine):

> Note that neither [and](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#and) nor [or](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#or) restrict the value and type they return to *False* and *True*, but rather **return the last evaluated argument**.

**Example**:

> ```py
> >>> 5 and 7
> 7
> >>> 7 and 5
> 5
> ```

Same applies for ***|*** *vs.* *or*, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The hint is in the name:

- Boolean operators are for performing **logical operations** (truth testing common in programming and formal logic)
- Bitwise operators are for **"bit-twiddling"** (low level manipulation of bits in byte and numeric data types)

While it is possible and indeed sometimes desirable (typically for efficiency reasons) to perform logical operations with bitwise operators, you should generally avoid them for such purposes to prevent subtle bugs and unwanted side effects.

If you need to manipulate bits, then the bitwise operators are purpose built. The fun book: [Hackers Delight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654) contains some cool and genuinely useful examples of what can be achieved with bit-twiddling.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean operation are logical operations.

Bitwise operations are operations on binary bits.

Bitwise operations:

```
>>> k = 1
>>> z = 3
>>> k & z  
1
>>> k | z  
3
```

The operations:

- AND `&`: 1 if both bits are 1, otherwise 0
- OR `|`: 1 if either bit is 1, otherwise 0
- XOR `^`: 1 if the bits are different, 0 if they're the same
- NOT `~`': Flip each bit

Some of the uses of bitwise operations:

1. Setting and Clearing Bits

Boolean operations:

```
>>> k = True
>>> z = False
>>> k & z  # and
False
>>> k | z  # or
True
>>>
```

Comment: For you boolean operations, don't you mean "and" and "or" instead of "&" and "|"?

Comment: Yes .. Yes .. Thanks , I do mean that.

Answer (score 0):

**Boolean 'and' vs. Bitwise '&':**

Pseudo-code/Python helped me understand the difference between these:

```
def boolAnd(A, B):
    # boolean 'and' returns either A or B
    if A == False:
        return A
    else:
        return B

def bitwiseAnd(A , B):
    # binary representation (e.g. 9 is '1001', 1 is '0001', etc.)

    binA = binary(A)
    binB = binary(B)



    # perform boolean 'and' on each pair of binaries in (A, B)
    # then return the result:
    # equivalent to: return ''.join([x*y for (x,y) in zip(binA, binB)])

    # assuming binA and binB are the same length
    result = []
    for i in range(len(binA)):
      compar = boolAnd(binA[i], binB[i]) 
      result.append(compar)

    # we want to return a string of 1s and 0s, not a list

    return ''.join(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Logical Operations

are usually used for conditional statements. For example:

```
if a==2 and b>10:
    # Do something ...
```

It means if both conditions (`a==2` and `b>10`) are true at the same time then the conditional statement body can be executed.

### Bitwise Operations

are used for data manipulation and extraction. For example, if you want to extract the four LSB (Least Significant Bits) of an integer, you can do this:

```
p & 0xF
```

Comment: The question's about Python, but it seemed like this answer was written in another language - maybe Ruby? Anyway I fixed it up. LMK if I missed anything.