# Make subset of array, based on values of two other arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, subset, boolean-logic

I am using Python. How to make a subselection of a vector, based on the values of two other vectors with the same length?

For example this three vectors

```
c1 = np.array([1,9,3,5])
c2 = np.array([2,2,3,2])
c3 = np.array([2,3,2,3])

c2==2
array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
c3==3
array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
elem  = (c2==2 and c3==3)
c1sel = c1[elem]
```

But the first statement results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

In Matlab, I would use:

```
elem  = find(c2==2 & c3==3);
c1sel = c1(elem);
```

How to do this in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
>>> c1[np.logical_and(c2==2, c3==3)]
array([9, 5])
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this does not work for more than two conditions. For three or more, I use the solution of mskimm.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, try

```
>>> c1[(c2==2) & (c3==3)]
array([9, 5])
```

cf) By [Python Operator Precedence](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html), the priority of `&` is upper than `==`. See the follow results.

```
>>> 1 == 1 & 2 == 2
False

>>> (1 == 1) & (2 == 2)
True
```

Comment: I still don't understand the difference between 'and' and '&'. I will read more about it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/python-boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep each of your conditions inside parenthesis:

```
In []: c1[(c2 == 2) & (c3 == 3)]
Out[]: array([9, 5])
```