# Print lines in a csv file if the values are consecutive

Tags: python, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4
11,12,27,28
5,6,101,102
111,112,55,56
1,7,33,34
3,4,55,57
```

I want to print lines if Value1 & Value2 are consecutive AND Value3 & Value4 are consecutive. The desired answer would be:

```
11,12,27,28
5,6,101,102
111,112,55,56
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
f = open('test.csv', 'rU')
for line in csv.reader(f):
    if line [1] == line [0] + 1 & line [4] == line [3] + 1:
        print line
f.close
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Change `&` to `and`, the [first is bitwise `AND`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/python-boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators) which you don't want, you want logical `AND`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problem, you have to change `&` to the word `and`. Read CoryKramers comment for more of an explanation as to why. A couple more things, it is always better to use `with open` when dealing with files. You want to skip the first line, since it is just a header line, so I added that. The values you read in from the CSV are strings, not integers, so trying to add to a string won't work, so you have to cast them as ints. Finally, the indicies you used were off, you did `1 0 4 3`, when there is no `4` index in the list. It should have been `1 0 3 2`. This outputs what you want:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'rU') as f:
    csvfile = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for line in csvfile:
        if 'Value1' not in line:
            if int(line[1]) == int(line[0]) + 1 and int(line[3]) == int(line[2]) + 1:
                print ','.join(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f) # Skip first line with headers
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        if line [1] == line [0] + 1 and line [4] == line [3] + 1:
            print line
```

see the and in the if because & is a bitwise AND operator

Comment: it is better practice to use `with open`

Comment: @heist: true, changed it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.

1. You're using `&` instead of `and`. (Look up bitwise & versus and)
2. You have a typo in your code: `line[4]` and `line[3]` should be `line[3]` and `line[2]` respectively.
3. You should be surrounding your `line[#]` with int() to cast it explicitly. So `int(line[#])`.
4. You need to advance your file so it doesn't hit the first line.

Finally, as a matter of style, you should not have extra spaces around `[#]` and you should use `with open`.

Here's some fixed code:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        if int(line[1] == int(line[0]) + 1 and int(line[3]) == int(line[2]) + 1:
            print(line)
```