# Most pythonic way to 'or' tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I have a method that returns a three element tuple of boolean values and I call it on a loop. I want to finally get a three element tuple containing the `or` result of the individual tuples. If the method only returned a boolean it would just be:

```
result = False
for j in some_list: # there is more processing in the loop, omitted
    result |= method(j)
return result
```

Can I generalize this in some elegant way to or the tuples that `method()` now returns? Of course I could do:

```
result = False, False, False
for j in some_list:
    res1, res2, res3 = method(j)
    result = res1 | result[0], res2 | result[1], res3 | result[2]
return result
```

but seems a bit inelegant.

EDIT: clarified I want to return the result in both cases - first a boolean then a tuple of booleans

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to be using the bitwise OR operator on `bool`s?

Comment: @Josh: That's what was used in the code - should I change it to or ?

Comment: I would think so. See [Python boolean operators vs bitwise operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3845018) if you'd like more info.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: don't you still find `result |= method(j)` more elegant (read readable) than result = result or method(j)`

Comment: Personally, no, because on reading `|` I would expect the types to be used for their bit values, not their boolean values.

Comment: You have a point - but I think here we reach opinion. To me `|` here is clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's unpack this a little.

There is no built in way to do an element-wise `or` (logical or bitwise) on two tuples. Morgan Thrapp's answer shows a good way to write your own, so if you want to maintain a running state in your for loop, that's the way I'd go. The generator expression is going to be easily understood by people familiar with Python - although I'd use `tuple(a or b for a, b in zip(result, new_result))` rather than `a | b` if I don't actually want the bitwise version.

Numpy arrays have a [`logical_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) function that works element-wise, but that'd be serious overkill if you just have a moderate number of tuples of booleans.

An alternative to keeping a running state is to collect all the result tuples and compute the final boolean value tuple from the list of result tuples. This wouldn't be appropriate if you're going to terminate the loop early (say if all elements of your accumulated result tuple are True) or if your loop has enough iterations that the memory use matters. Depending on your tastes, though, it might be clearer. This is essentially the same decision as keeping a running total of numeric values versus just collecting the values as the loop runs and summing afterwards, and would be my preferred approach if for instances you rework your for loop as an iterator of result tuples.

That would look something like:

```
result_list = []
for j in some_list:
    result_list.append(method(j))
result = tuple(any(grouped) for grouped in zip(*result_list))
```

`zip` on the star-expanded result list will group all the first/second/third values of your list of tuples as n-length tuples where n is the number of results, and `any` effectively `or`s them together. EG:

```
>>> result_list = [(False, True, False), (True, False, False), (False, False, False), (True, True, False)]
>>> zip(*result_list)
[(False, True, False, True), (True, False, False, True), (False, False, False, False)]
>>> tuple(any(grouped) for grouped in zip(*result_list))
(True, True, False)
```

Since `or` over booleans is equivalent to addition over numbers, and `any` is equivalent to `sum`, you can consider similar models with ints. The for loop/multiple assignment version:

```
sums = (0, 0, 0)
for j in some_list:
    result = method(j)
    sums[0] += result[0]
    sums[1] += result[1]
    sums[2] += result[2]
```

vs the generator expression running sum version:

```
sums = (0, 0, 0)
for j in some_list:
    result = method(j)
    sums = (a + b for a, b in zip(sums, result))
```

vs accumulating and summing the list of results:

```
result_list = []
for j in some_list:
    result_list.append(method(j))
sums = tuple(sum(grouped) for grouped in zip(*result_list))
```

This version is particularly nice if your `for` loop doesn't have any other body, since you can collapse the whole thing into whatever level of generator expressions/list comprehensions you like:

```
result_list = [method(j) for j in some_list]
sums = tuple(sum(grouped) for grouped in zip(*result_list))
```

or:

```
sums = tuple(sum(grouped) for grouped in zip(*(method(j) for j in some_list)))
```

Comment: Hmm - will ponder over this a bit :) Still how would this adapt to the loop ? I mean would it not need even more lines ?

Comment: This version doesn't need an explicit for loop - the generator expression (`for grouped in zip(some_list)`) takes care of the iteration.

Comment: See the loop in my question - it's a big loop

Comment: This is the wrong zipping, not what the OP is asking for. See the last line of the second snippet in the question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - how so? The snippet shows an ongoing or of each element of the result tuple, so zipping the list of results tuples should group all the first elements, then all the second, etc.

Comment: This doesn't use OP's `method` at all.

Comment: The question is asking for the pairwise comparison of the initial `result` tuple and the tuple returned from the method: `zip(result, ret_val)`.

Comment: The initial result tuple is just all `False`. The OP asks for "a tuple containing the `or` result of the individual tuples", which is exactly what this does. Only question is whether or not getting the list of result tuples and then reducing is appropriate compared to maintaining a running sum in the loop. Rework it with ints and it's just the difference between and initial zero Val and iteratively adding or accumulating a list of values and using `sum`.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. It was me misinterpreting the question. (I was also assuming the initial `False, False, False` was a dummy value for the question, not the real code.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell - actually, you were right that it was the wrong zipping, I forgot the all-important `*` expansion to make it convolve the tuples. Fixed and expanded.

Comment: The `result_list.append(method(j))` is what I thought of using after reading the helpful and not so helpful answers and comments here - thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in a list comprehension with zip.

```
result = False, True, False
xor = True, True, False
result = [a|b for a,b in zip(result,xor)]
print(result)
```

Or in the case of your example:

```
result = False, False, False
for j in some_list:
    xor = method(j)
    result = [a|b for a,b in zip(result,xor)]
```

If it HAS to be a tuple, you can change the list comp to a generator and wrap it in `tuple()`.

You can also move the call to `method(j)` inside the call to zip instead of assigning it to an intermediate variable. I think it makes it a little less readable, but it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D It's much more efficient than doing it manually, plus this will work no matter how many values you have. I don't understand what solution you think would be more "elegant".

Comment: You mean that `result = res1 | result[0], res2 | result[1], res3 | result[2]` is less efficient than `result = [a|b for a,b in zip(result,xor)]` ? Can you time it ?

Comment: The most elegant would be `tuple1 | tuple2` - unfortunately it's a Syntax error

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D The difference in time is going to be negligible for only 3 values. Again, I'm not sure what you're looking for if this isn't it.

Comment: You referred to the timing - and you are wrong, the way in the question is hands down faster.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: The way you're doing it — explicitly processing each of the three element tuple's components — would be faster. Apparently that's what you think "pythonic" means. Morgan's code will handle tuples of any size unchanged and is slightly shorter, which is another equally valid meaning. Unfortunately the generality comes at a price (which is often the case unless it's handled by a Python built-in).

Comment: @martineau: thanks - that's a possible answer - by pythonic I did not mean speed only - I meant the straightforwardness of `result |= method(j)`. Speed is always a concern in a loop body of course. The `any` answer by @PeterDeGlopper comes closer to the point - but next developer reading the code would be happier to read the code in my question than `any(grouped[0]) for grouped in zip(somelist)`. So there is no `tuple1 | tuple2` finally ?

Comment: There is no built in element-wise `or` on tuples, no.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: There's nothing built-in that will perform `tuple | tuple` the way you want. If you changed your data representation to bit values, you could effectively `|` as many elements together at once as you wished since Python supports arbitrarily long integers. Lastly, speed is _not_ always a concern, some even think [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).