# Pandas boolean algebra: True if True in both columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a boolean vector that is created by the comparison of two input boolean vectors.  I can use a for loop, but is there a better way to do this?

My ideal solution would look like this:

```
df['A'] = [True, False, False, True]
df['B'] = [True, False, False, False]
C = ((df['A']==True) or (df['B']==True)).as_matrix()
print C

>>> True, False, False, True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
C = (df['A']) | (df['B'])
C

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

You could then leave this as a series or convert it to a list or array

Comment: Got it!  The link goes deeper into your solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/python-boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) method with `axis=1` to search in index. It also will work for any number of columns where you have `True` values:

```
In [1105]: df
Out[1105]: 
       B      A
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False   True

In [1106]: df.any(axis=1)
Out[1106]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```