# Logical vs. bitwise operator AND

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I don’t understand the difference between `&` and `and`, even if I read some other questions about it.

My code is:

```
f=1
x=1

f==1 & x==1
Out[60]: True

f==1 and x==1
Out[61]: True

f=1
x=2

f==1 and x==2
Out[64]: True

f==1 & x==2
Out[65]: False
```

Why is it the second `&` `False`, whereas the first is `True`?

Comment: you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3845032/4941927

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `&` has higher operator precedence than `==`.

```
>>> (f == 1) & (x == 2)
True
>>> f == (1 & x) == 2
False
```

Perhaps this seems unintuitive, but `&` is really meant to be used between numbers for particular kinds of calculations:

```
>>> 3 & 5
1
```

so it has similar precedence to operators like `+` and `*`, which sensibly should be evaluated before `==`. It's not meant to be used in a similar manner to `and` at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that '&' has higher priority than `==`. If you put your last statement like:

```
(f==1) & (x==2)
```

You will get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, your code is:

```
f == (1 & x) == 2
```

`1 & 2` is 0:

```
00000001
00000010 &
--------
00000000
```

So your final statement looks:

```
1 == 0 == 2
```

Which is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Logical AND (`and`) gives you an answer in true or false (boolean answer) whereas Bitwise AND (`&`) operator gives you an answer in digits after converting them to binary and applying a truth table on numbers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).