# Learning python from scratch

Tags: python

I am learning python from scratch. I have written one small code for a rock paper scissor game. where 1 input is from the user and another input from PC using the random library. I know my code is not perfect. but I am not understanding one thing when I was trying to test my code.

Here is my code.

```
import random
from time import sleep
print("Let's play the game")

print("For Rock Choose 1")
print("For Paper Choose 2")
print("For Scissors Choose 3")


a = int(input("Enter the number "))

if a == 1:
    print("You Choose Rock")
elif a == 2:
    print("You Choose Paper")
elif a == 3:
    print("You Chosse Scissors")
else:
    print("Invalid Input")

print ("Now taking input from PC")
sleep (3)

b = random.randint(1,3)
if b == 1:
    print("PC has given Rock")
elif b == 2:
    print ("PC has given Paper")
elif b==3:
    print ("PC has given Scissors")

if a == b:
    print ("Match Tie")
elif a ==1 & b == 3:
    print ("You Win")
elif a == 2 & b == 1:
    print ("You Win")
elif a == 3 & b == 2:
    print ("You Win")
else:
    print ("You Loose")
```

You can clearly see i choose 2 and PC choose 1. then the output i got is "You Loose" how it can possible in condition i clearly written if a == 2 & b == 1 print ("You Win")

[image]

While testing this code (selected code of image) I found one thing and I got confused.

Comment: When you post text, please post text, not photographs of text. This is a site for programming, not [photography.se]. We want to read&analyze the text, not write an essay critiquing its use of color and perspective.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logical vs. bitwise operator AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310789/logical-vs-bitwise-operator-and)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `and` rather than `&`

In Python, the `&` is a [bitwise operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) whereas you want to use a [conditional](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

```py
if a == b:
    print ("Match Tie")
elif a ==1 and b == 3:
    print ("You Win")
elif a == 2 and b == 1:
    print ("You Win")
elif a == 3 and b == 2:
    print ("You Win")
else:
    print ("You Loose")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using bit operators. The `&` with 1 and 2 you have:

```
1 = 00001
2 = 00010

1 & 2 = 0
```

You should use `and` instead of `&`