# Randomly flip one bit in a binary list

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I am using python-3.x, and I am trying to do mutation on a binary string that will flip one bit of the elements from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 by random, I tried some methods but didn't work I don't know where is the problem:

```
x=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

def mutation (x, muta):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if random.random() < muta:
            x[i] = type(x[i])(not x[i])
    return x,
print (x)
```

The output for example should be x=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0] or x=[1, 0, 0, 0, 0] and so on....

Also, I tried this one:

```
MUTATION_RATE = 0.5
CHROMO_LEN = 6
def mutate(x):
    x = ""
    for i in range(CHROMO_LEN):
        if (random.random() < MUTATION_RATE):
            if (x[i] == 1):
                x += 0
            else:
                x += 1
        else:
            x += x[i]
    return x
print(x)
```

please any suggestion or advice will be appreciated

Comment: What's with `type(x[i])(not x[i])`...?

Comment: The value of x[i]

Comment: But why are you doing `type(x[i])(...)`?

Comment: I am trying to switch values

Comment: Yes, *I understand that*. I don't understand why you are using **`type`**

Comment: I think this the right functions as I understand from the web page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type maybe I am wrong!!!

Comment: Why not just `int`?

Comment: **Why** , can you explain **why** you are using `type`. I know what it does already.

Comment: I don't know just trying this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're calling the function before printing `x`:

```
def mutation(x):
    # your code without the trailing comma

mutation(x)
print(x)
```

In Python, creating a new list is usually preferable to mutating an old one. I would write your first function like this (I converted the integers to booleans because you're just flipping them:

```
x = [False, False, False, False]


def mutation(x, muta):
    return [not e if random.random() < muta else e
            for e in x]
```

Change `x` by assigning to it again:

```
x = mutation(x, .5)
```

Your original function is working if you remove the comma after the `return`:

```
def mutation(x, muta):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if random.random() < muta:
            x[i] = type(x[i])(not x[i])
    return x
x = [False, False, False, False]


mutation(x, .5)
Out[8]: [False, False, True, False]

mutation(x, .5)
Out[9]: [True, True, True, False]
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it is preferable to create a new list rather than mutating an old one... that totally depends on your use-case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess it is more of an opinion, but unless performance is an issue, I really appreciate functions not messing with the values I put into them without explicit assignment when I call the function.

Comment: @Ben I am using Spyder python environment, does it make a difference? for me it returning the same result [0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: @azeez it shouldn't... Just to be sure though, close Spyder, start it up again, then paste the code in. That will restart the interpreter and clear away any possible definitions you've already made.

Comment: @Ben I did but now it gives me an error: NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Comment: @Ben sorry I was missing "import random"

Answer (score 0):

You could also use python's [XOR operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) to flip bits, which will flip between '1' and '0':

`x[1] = x[1] ^ 1`

See also: [Python XOR preference: bitwise operator vs. boolean operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096616/python-xor-preference-bitwise-operator-vs-boolean-operators?noredirect=1&lq=1)