# How to use AND or OR condition in when in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to evaluate two conditions in when like this :-

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    'trueVal', F.when(df.value < 1 OR df.value2  == 'false' , 0 ).otherwise(df.value))
```

For this I get 'invalid syntax' for using 'OR'

Even I tried using nested when statements :-

```python
df = df.withColumn(
    'v', 
    F.when(df.value < 1,(F.when( df.value =1,0).otherwise(df.value))).otherwise(df.value)
)
```

For this i get `'keyword can't be an expression'` for nested when statements.

How could I use multiple conditions in `when` any work around ?

Comment: This question is a bit old, but your `'keyword can't be an expression'` error is actually a result of using a single `=` rather than `==` in the inner `when`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

[`pyspark.sql.functions.when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) takes a Boolean Column as its condition. When using PySpark, it's often useful to think "Column Expression" when you read "Column".

Logical operations on PySpark columns use the [bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators/25949622):

- `&` for `and`
- `|` for `or`
- `~` for `not`

When combining these with comparison operators such as `<`, parenthesis are often needed.

In your case, the correct statement is:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn('trueVal',
    F.when((df.value < 1) | (df.value2 == 'false'), 0).otherwise(df.value))
```

See also: [SPARK-8568](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8568)

Comment: "parenthesis are often needed" - thanks - that's what made the difference for me!

Comment: The first link should be to the `when` function, right? Not `where`?

Comment: Can you elaborate why Spark treats columns as expressions?

Comment: '"parenthesis are often needed" - thanks - that's what made the difference for me! ' <- same here!!