# if elif statement with & is giving unexpected output

Tags: python, if-statement, fizzbuzz

I am trying to learn python & while trying to solve this quiz on a website, I get a strange error , which is that the assertion fails for the 2nd parameter , while the if elif statement is correct & shall give the correct output (but it is giving a wrong unexpected output)

The error is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/pythonSnakegame/snakeGame.py
Fizz Buzz
Traceback (most recent call last):
Fizz Buzz
  File "C:/Users/..../PycharmProjects/pythonSnakegame/snakeGame.py", line 28, in <module>
    assert checkio(6) == "Fizz", "6 is divisible by 3"
AssertionError: 6 is divisible by 3

Process finished with exit code 1

def checkio(number):
    # Your code here
    # It's main function. Don't remove this function
    # It's using for auto-testing and must return a result for check.
    if number % 3 == 0 & number % 5 == 0:
        result = "Fizz Buzz"
    elif number % 3 == 0:
        result = "Fizz"
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        result = "Buzz"

    # replace this for solution
    print (result)
    return result
    # return str(number)


# Some hints:
# Convert a number in the string with str(n)

# These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert checkio(15) == "Fizz Buzz", "15 is divisible by 3 and 5"
    assert checkio(6) == "Fizz", "6 is divisible by 3"
    assert checkio(5) == "Buzz", "5 is divisible by 5"
    assert checkio(7) == "7", "7 is not divisible by 3 or 5"
    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to review your tests and earn cool rewards!")
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The boolean and operator is `and`, not `&`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators

Comment: For the record, the statement breaks down like this: `(number % 3) == (0 & (number % 5)) == 0`. So the divisibility by 5 check is completely removed by the `0 &` in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&` operator is for **binary** operations, you should use `and` (**boolean** operator) instead.

> I kept wondering why it was not working

The `&` is disabling the module operation check for `5`, so basically all divisible by 3 where getting `True`, check this output test:

```
number = 12
number % 3 == 0 & number % 5 == 0
True
```