# Python conditional evaluation

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I expect below code to work properly, since first condition if false, but it throughs  `IndexError: string index out of range`. What am I missing?

```
 a = False
 sample_strign = 'test'
 if (a == True) & (sample_strign[7] == 's'):
        print('foo')
```

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator and does not short circuit.

Comment: Also, it's more Pythonic to check just `a` or even `a is True` than `a == True`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boolean operators vs Bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` is a bit-wise operator.  If you want the interpreter to "short-circuit" the logic, use the logical operator `and`.

```
if a and (sample_strign[7] == 's'):
```

Answer (score 1):

`sameple_strign` doesn't have a 7th index which will raise an exception, you should use something like:

```
if a and len(sample_strign) > 7:
    if sample_strign[7] == 's':
        print('foo')
```