# Problems regarding Python if statement

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

I am running Python 3.6.4 with Anaconda and Spyder.

Does anyone know why the following is happening?

When I execute the following code python prints "yes" which it is obviously wrong.

```
import numpy as np
a = 0
c = np.ones(150)
b = np.ones(10)
if a < len(c) & len(b) < 3:
    print('yes')
```

While when I made a slight modification the condition is not satisfied and python does not print anything

```
a = 0
c = np.ones(152)
b = np.ones(10)
if a < len(c) & len(b) < 3:
    print('yes')
```

Furthermore if I change "&" with "and" everything is working as expected.

Comment: `&` is *bitwise* and, `and` is *logical* and

Comment: Does that not suggest you should focus your attention on researching the difference between `&` and `and`?

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I cannot understand why the first block of code prints "yes" while the second block of code does not print anything

Comment: See explanation of bitwise vs Boolean [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators)

Comment: The main difference that you see is summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25949622/2285236). `&` has a higher precedence.

Comment: @user633183, But is this really the problem? Nothing wrong with using bitwise operators here. Provided they are using correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now. I should use "and" or use parenthesis.

Comment: @PaulRooney I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25949622/2285236) covers that?

Comment: `&` is useful when chaining boolean arrays, but you can't use those in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to operator chaining, `&` takes precedence. Try this instead, notice the brackets:

```
if (a < len(c)) & (len(b) < 3):
    print('yes')
```

`&` is a bitwise operator and as such may be used to combine two Boolean conditions. In Python, `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Bitwise, `len(c) & len(b)` evaluates to 2, so you are actually evaluating:

```
if 0 < 2 < 3:  # i.e. 0 < 2 and separately 2 < 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`&` is a bitwise and. 
`and` is logical and. (Use this! It's cleaner and more pythonic).

You can also include more parentheses `(a < len(c)) & (len(b) < 3):` and that will work, despite being ugly.