# Can Someone Explain the difference between Logical and Boolean And in this Case,

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, boolean-logic

Can Someone Explain the Difference between logical and Boolean & in this code

```
def isprime(num):
    return [i for i in range(2,num) if num%i==0]==[]

num_which_are_prime=[i for i in range(1,100) if isprime(i) and i!=1]
print(num_which_are_prime)

num_which_are_prime=[i for i in range(1,100) if isprime(i) & i!=1]
print(num_which_are_prime)
```

Shows this:

> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
>
> [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 70, 72, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 98, 99]

Comment: Please see [Formatting Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to get your code formatted correctly. Images of code aren't great either.

Comment: Please add your code (not image of code). It's time consuming writing your code again and explain the answer. It's easier to copy your code and edit it.

Comment: Please write a brief description of your problem. The problem statement that you have posted is not sufficient to understand the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boolean operators vs Bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators)

Comment: `&` is bitwise operator, it does NOT produce boolean True/False value.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the improper use of `&` as stated in the comment.

It's because of the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

- `and` has lower priority than `!=`
- `!=` has lower priority than `&`

So the first expression is evaluated as `isprime(i) and (i != 1)`, the second expression is evaluated as `((isprime(i) & i) != 1)`.

**EDIT**

To explain output for the `&` version. As stated in the comment, `&` is a bitwise AND operator. Boolean expressions `True` and `False` can be represented as a single bit `1` and `0`, respectively. As a result, the expression `isprime(i) & i` tests only the very first bit (the right-most bit)

- For every non-prime number you get `0 & i` which always evaluates to 0 and `0 != 1` is always `True`.
- Every prime number, except for 2, is an odd number (that is the first bit is 1). As such, `1 & x1`, where `x` is arbitrary binary string, will evaluate to 1 and `1 != 1` will always be `False`.
- And lastly, 2 is a prime number but it's even (first bit is 0). So, `1 & 10` will be 0, and `0 != 1` evaluates to `True`.

Your output, therefore, contains only non-prime numbers and a number 2.