# Python 'if' condition doesn't work with shorthand 'or'

Tags: python

What is wrong here on the method a|b==0 vs a==0 or b==0 ?

```
def validate(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)
    if (a|b == 0) or c == 0:
        return "Invalid"
    else:
        return "Valid"
print("Test 1: ", validate(0,1,2))
print("Test 2: ", validate(0,1,0))
```

---

```
>0 1 2
Test 1:  Valid
```

---

```
>0 1 0
Test 2:  Invalid
```

Comment: There's no such "shorthand or" syntax in Python. `|` is a bitwise OR operator.

Comment: Where did you even get that idea? Perl 6?

Comment: The pipe symbol `|` represents *bitwise* or, are you looking for *logical* or? (literal `or`).

Comment: @eyllanesc although this question is framed as a duplicate of this question - it seems to be an misunderstanding about how chained logic operators work in python. I suspect it's still a duplicate - but I don't think the target you've given is the best possible one.

Comment: @Shadow 
Why is my decision wrong? I see that many of the answers answer the difference between the two, I think that you are only seeing the question marked as correct and not the others

Comment: @eyllanesc that's fair, I stand corrected. Answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25949622/1594286) do indeed address this confusion.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have confused python's `or` and `|`.

Understandable, given that the or operator in many langages is `|` (or more commonly `||`).

This [page lists python's operators](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators)

Try your example again, but using `or` instead of `|`

```
if (a or b == 0) or c == 0:
```

If I'm reading your question correctly however, I think you're trying to do this;

```
if (a == b == 0) or c == 0:
```

This is the shortcut-syntax in python for checking if both `a` and `b` is equal to 0.

EDIT: As per clarification;

> Requirement is to confirm 0 is not passed as an argument to the function

If you can safely assume that your arguments are going to be ints, then I would take the following approach:

```
if a and b and c:
    pass  # valid
else:
    pass  # invalid
```

`0` is falsey - so lets use the fact. Otherwise, there isn't really a 'shortcut' way to do what you're doing.

Comment: thanks, I understand the mistake here. But trying with your first example, it still shows the same error                                                                                                         
 
`def validate(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)
    if (a or b == 0) or c == 0:
        return "Invalid"
    else:
        return "Valid"
print("Test 1: ", validate(0,1,2))
print("Test 2: ", validate(0,1,0))`                                                                                            
 >>0 1 2
Test 1:  Valid
0 1 0
Test 2:  Invalid

Comment: Just switching `or` for `|` doesn't fix this code, since `or` doesn't work like that either.

Comment: @ɐɯıɥɐɹ What about the second part of my answer? If that isn't doing what you think it should, then I think it might be a good idea to edit your question and state exactly when this should be true and false with examples of both.

Comment: Second suggestion works like `and` and only if both a and b are 0. Here is what works for me `if a ==0 or b == 0 or c == 0` or `if 0 in (a,b,c)` . Requirement is to confirm 0 is not passed as an argument to the function