# Why the output of below code is like this

Tags: python, bitwise-and

As per my understanding of bitwise operators, below code should only execute when both i and j are equal to 5, for all others values of i and j, if condition should evaluate to False. but I am getting the following output:

```
for i in range(30):
    for j in range(30):
        if i == 5 & j == 5:
            print(i, j, i & j, bin(i==5), bin(j==5), i == 5 & j == 5)
```

#### Output:

```
# i, j, i & j, binary value of i, binary value of j, bitwise and of i == 5 and j == 5
5 5 5 0b1 0b1 True
5 7 5 0b1 0b0 False
5 13 5 0b1 0b0 False
5 15 5 0b1 0b0 False
5 21 5 0b1 0b0 False
5 23 5 0b1 0b0 False
5 29 5 0b1 0b0 False
```

Questions:

1. Binary value of both i and j is 1 only for 1st case, then why other cases are getting printed?
2. why the result is getting printed where i & j is evaluating to 5
3. If I change the order of conditions in above if statement, i acquires the values 5, 7, 13, 15, 21, 23, 29 while j remains 5 and other output is same as well. why?
4. For above code, i = 7 and j = 5, i & j evaluates to 5 as well. Then why it is not getting printed?

Comment: Check your code please. I'm getting different results. What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority, which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or **bitwise** operation. Also unlike C, expressions like a < b < c have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:

so here:

```
i == 5 & j == 5
```

what happens is that `5 & j` is tested against `i` and `5` for equality. So parenthesizing would work but the proper way is to use *logical* `and` operator which has a higher precedence:

```
i == 5 and j == 5
```

it also *short-circuits*, which means that if `i != 5`, `j` is not even tested (faster execution). Applies perfectly to this example.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I realized my mistake a day later.

Answer (score 2):

Use the operator "and" instead of "&". it will solve your issue.

and : logical operator
& : bitwise operator

```
for i in range(30):
    for j in range(30):
        if i == 5 and j == 5:
            print(i, j, i & j, bin(i==5), bin(j==5), i == 5 & j == 5)
```

Result :

```
5 5 5 0b1 0b1 True
```

Reference 1:

[Difference between 'and' (boolean) vs. '&' (bitwise) in python. Why difference in behavior with lists vs numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i)

Reference 2 :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845072/1855988

Comment: Why is this the case? Please add an explanation, or even just a link, as to why this is necessary/what the difference is.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi, I was editing my answer to give more details.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer you missed the brackets:

```
for i in range(30):
    for j in range(30):
        if (i == 5) &  (j == 5):
            print(i, j, i & j, bin(i==5), bin(j == 5), i == 5 & j == 5)
```

First Evaluate (i==5) and (j==5) then compare the resulting boolean with the other resulting boolean.

Or as mentioned below just use and. If you want to explore this a little bit more just look at the result of the following:

```
for x in range(0, 32):
    print(x & 2, bin(x), bin(2), bin(x & 2))
```

How it works in Detail you can find here:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators