# Number Comparison in Python displays wrong result

Tags: python

I'm starting to practice Python programming so please excuse if it's some very basic concept for you.

I'm trying to print result based on number comparison.

User Input: Any number between 1 to 100
Outputs: Based on comparisons, the output should be printed accordingly. Please look at the code below:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: ").strip())

if 0<x<101:
    if (x%2 == 1):
       print("Weird")
    elif (x%2 == 0 & 1<x<6):
       print("Not Weird -  between 2 to 5; inclusive")
    elif (x%2 == 0 & 5<x<21):
       print("Weird -  between 5 to 20; inclusive")
    elif (x%2 == 0 & x>=20):
       print("Not Weird - Greater than 20")
    else:
        print("Please enter a number between 1 & 100, limits inclusive. Exiting program...")
```

It does the job for first 3 `if` comparisons. But if I input any even number above 20, it prints the final `else` loop statement.

I modified the last `if` to `20<x<100`, then it runs properly.

For some reason, I can't get the `x>20` condition work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use "and" instead of "&". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators

Comment: did you want larger than 20 or larger and equal to 20

Comment: @outflanker: Thanks, it works with `and`. I wasn't aware of this difference. Thanks again.

Comment: @KevinNg: Maybe the code I pasted confused you. But it hardly matters if it's `>20` or `>=20`, right? I got that working with the response from outflanker above.

Comment: @knowone that is true, I did not notice the 5<x<21. So your below clause would not matter whether > or >=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Answer: Use `and` instead of `&`. `and` is for boolean operators and `&` is used for bitwise operations (can be good for arrays which this is not).

Another note, you have `5<x<20` which is not actually inclusive of 5 and 20 (use `5<=x<=20` or `4<x<21`) and `x>=20` is not just greater than 20 it is also equal (use `x>20`). However if you actually want to restrict it to less than or equal to 100 obviously use `20<x<101`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by `outflanker` in the comments above, pasting the corrected code.

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: ").strip())

if 0<x<101:
    if (x%2 == 1):
       print("Weird")
    elif (x%2 == 0 and 1<x<6):
       print("Not Weird -  between 2 to 5; inclusive")
    elif (x%2 == 0 and 5<x<21):
       print("Weird -  between 5 to 20; inclusive")
    elif (x%2 == 0 and x>=20):
       print("Not Weird - Greater than 20")
    else:
        print("Please enter a number between 1 & 100, limits inclusive. Exiting program...")
```