# TypeError when trying to do a Boolean AND

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I'm trying to learn python but I got stuck on some practice code. I want to check to see if two of the three items I am putting into a list named `guesses`  are in another list named `favorite` while checking to see if the third item I am putting into the list `guesses` is not in the other list `favorite`.

```
games = ['CS:GO', 'MK11', 'Black Ops 3', 'League of Legends', 'Osu!', 'Injustice 2', 'Dont Starve', 'Super Smash Brothers: Ultimate', 'God of War', 'Kingdom Hearts 3', 'Red Dead Redemption 2', 'Spider-Man', ]

favorite = ['God of War', 'CS:GO', 'Spider-Man']
guesses = ['', '', '']

print('I like ' + str(len(games) + 1) + ' games and here there are:' + str(games[:8]) + '\n' + str(games[9:]))
print('Can you guess whats are my favorite three games out of my list?')
guesses[0] = input()
print('Whats game number 2?')
guesses[1] = input()
print('Whats game number 3?')
guesses[2] = input()

# if all(x in favorite for x in guesses):
#     print('Yes! Those are my three favorite games!')

if guesses[0] in favorite & guesses[1] in favorite & guesses[2] not in favorite:
    print('Sorry, ' + str(guesses[0]) + ' & ' + str(guesses[1]) + ' are two of my favorite games but unfortunately ' + str(guesses[2]) + ' is not.')
```

My issue is that I thought my if statement above would work, may someone please explain why I am getting this TypeError below:

```
  line 18, in <module>
    if guesses[0] in favorite & guesses[1] in favorite & guesses[2] not in favorite:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'str'
```

I also understand that the `all` function works in this case to see if all of the items if both lists are equal but I want to know if two of the three items are equal while the third isn't.

Thank you.

Comment: in python boolean AND operator uses the word `and`, bitwise operator is `&`.  so you want something like `guesses[0] in favorite and guesses[1] in favorite`

Comment: not related to the question but why are you only printing the first 8 elements of `games`? like you are not displaying `'God of War'` or `'Spider-Man'` but those are in your favourites? seems like a bit of a cheat for this program...

Comment: Thank you all for the help. And Tadhg I choice to slice the list when it was being printed and add a new line before printing the rest of the list, as it would have ran on instead of wrapping.

Comment: Your indexing is all over the place

Comment: Related: [Boolean operators vs Bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3845018/4518341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are use a single ampersand, not `and` in your final if statement.

```py
if guesses[0] in favorite and guesses[1] in favorite and guesses[2] not in favorite:
    print('Sorry, ' + str(guesses[0]) + ' & ' + str(guesses[1]) + ' are two of my favorite games but unfortunately ' + str(guesses[2]) + ' is not.')
```

A single ampersand means [*bitwise and*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) which is done on binary types, and not [*boolean and*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Operations) which is what you require.

---

As an aside (if this matters to your program), it is worth noting that this only checks one permutation of your `guesses` list (i.e. what if `guesses[0]` was not in `favourites` instead of `guesses[2]`?)

Although probably not the most efficient or elegant, you could achieve this with a `map` and `sum`:

```
# Turns each element of guesses into 1 if it's in favourites or 0 if not.
in_favourites = map(lambda x: 1 if x in favourites else 0, guesses)
# Sum the list of 1's and 0's
number_in_favourites = sum(in_favourites)
# Do your check (you could do number_in_favourites >= 2)
if number_in_favourites == 2:
    print("Woopee!")

# Or more concisely:
if sum(map(lambda x: x in favourites, guesses)) == 2:
    print("Woopee!")
```

*(Disclaimer, I'm writing this code purely in a browser so I haven't tested it, but it should be roughly like that!)*

Comment: Thank you th3ant, you have answered my question thoroughly, and have given me somemore reading to do haha. Thanks again.