# How to convert this to a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert this part of the code to a list comprehension, however my knowledge of this method is still very weak and it does not occur to me how, if you could help me, I would appreciate it.

```
list_1 = ["h",'i',' ', 'w','o','r','l','d'] 
list_2 = ["h",'i',' ', 'm','o','o','n']   

list_3 = []

for word in list_1:
    if word in list_2 and word not in list_3:
        list_3.append(word)

print(list_3)
```

Comment: Your question had some translation errors so I fixed them. Hope that helps! If I misunderstood please let me know.

Comment: please show us your desired output.

Comment: @Errol I'm inferring that it already works properly, but OP just wants to convert it to a comprehension.

Comment: my english is so bad bro,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, this works:

```
list_3 = [word for word in list_1 if word in list_2]
print(list_3)  # -> ['h', 'i', ' ', 'o']
```

If you want to keep excluding duplicates in `list_3` then it gets a bit more complicated. Check out [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists). For example, this will work in Python 3.7+:

```
dict_3 = {word: None for word in list_1 if word in list_2}
print(list(dict_3))  # -> ['h', 'i', ' ', 'o']
```

Comment: thanks bro do not notice that I have to use the if condition in these cases

Comment: @wjandrea This is not the correct answer, it breaks for an input like `list_1 = list("hi there")` and `list_3` will  include duplicates...

Comment: @Guimoute Added a solution for that

Comment: bro but here elements are missing

Comment: @epalaarepa What do you mean?

Comment: ['h', 'i', ' ', 'o']                                                                                                                       ['h', 'i', ' ', 'w', 'm', 'r', 'l', 'd', 'o']

Comment: the second list is the one that should quit the function

Comment: @epalaarepa What function? What do you mean by "quit"?

Comment: ['h', 'i', ' ', 'w', 'm', 'r', 'l', 'd', 'o']       
the purpose of the function is to generate a new list and put non-repeating elements inside the new list

Comment: @epalaarepa The code in your question doesn't do that. I'm not a mind-reader... Ask a new question if you need.

Comment: but in the code it is seen in the    `code if word in list_2 and word not in list_3: `

check and add the words that are not repeated

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
[list_3.append(w) for w in list_1 if (w in list_2) and (w not in list_3)]
list_3
```

Output:

`['h', 'i', ' ', 'o']`

Enjoy!

Comment: This works, but the style is bad. [Don't use comprehensions for side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/4518341), and [don't use bitwise operators when you should use logical operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3845018/4518341).

Comment: @wjandrea yes, my method may be a bit computationally expensive, but it solves the example given. Unless you have a complex code for a large program, this should not be a problem. for the bitwise vs boolean operators, you are right the boolean `and` makes more sense here.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it is using set data structure.

```
list_1 = ["h",'i',' ', 'w','o','r','l','d'] 
list_2 = ["h",'i',' ', 'm','o','o','n'] 
set_1 = set(list_1)
set_2 = set(list_2)
set_3 = set_1 & set_2
print(set_3)
```

output

```
{' ', 'o', 'i', 'h'}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is all you need

next time please do more reaserach

```
list_1 = ["h",'i',' ', 'w','o','r','l','d'] 
list_2 = ["h",'i',' ', 'm','o','o','n','']   

list_3 = []

for i in range(0, len(list_1)):
    if list_1[i] != list_2[i]
        list_3.append(list_1[i])

print(list_3)
```

result:

```
['m','o','n']
```

Comment: that's list comprehension?

Comment: @epalaarepa It's what your code wanted to do, I can explain

Comment: @epalaarepa this code scans through both lists one by one and every time the letter is different, a boolean for the if statement returns true and appends to the new list.

Comment: I thought of something like this                                                                               
list_3 = [ word  for word in list_1 and word not in list_2 ]

Comment: @epalaarepa The logic is coorect but the syntax had problems

Comment: NameError: name 'word' is not defined 
gives me this error

Comment: @epalaarepa when you use your code, word is just like my i, a variable that goes through 0 to 8 because your string is 8 objects long

Comment: If not, why if the letter according to what I understand is the one that is saved in the new list, and the program says that the letter is not defined

Comment: @epalaarepa that is because of the fact that list_1 is 8 long and list_2 is 7 long so when word goes to 8, the whole thing crashes

Comment: your answer is fine but what I need is to reduce the size of the code for that is the understanding of lists as well as I put the code it runs fine

Comment: @epalaarepa wjandrea's answer is more strait forward, mabe go check out his?

Comment: @AlexLiu10101 Sorry, I should have mentioned, OP's looking for a list comprehension. The question had a translation problem that I fixed, "understanding" -> "comprehension".