# Got a problem with Python conditional structure

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation

I have an if conditional structure in my python code and i got a problem with how its executing...
I expect the first nested if to print `The input choice you entered is out of range")` when `false` is returned but its executing the code in the `else` which is `you entered 4` in the second nested if, i expect it to execute the `false` counterpart of the first nested if which is  `print("nThe input choice you entered is out of range")`, Am i indenting the wrong way or?Please help me

```
message=input("Enter the message you want encrypted")
if(message.isalpha()& message.__len__()!=0):
    options=("1. Substitution Cypher","2.Playfair Cypher","3. Transposition Cypher", "4. Product Cypher","RSA Cypher")
    print("Choose an encryption Cypher you would like to use?")
    print(options[0])
    print(options[1])
    print(options[2])
    print(options[3])


    choice=int(input("Please reply with a number for choice of Cypher"))
    ##USER NEEDS CHOICE OF encryption algorithm to use
    if(choice>=1&choice<=4):
        if(choice==1):
            print("You chose 1")
        elif(choice==2):
            print("You chose 2")
        elif(choice==3):
          print("You chose 3")
        else:
         print("You chose 4")
    else:
        print("nThe input choice you entered is out of rage")
else:
    print("User input is required in form of alphabet format")
```

Comment: It works if you replace bitwise comparison `&` with standard `and`, but I can't explain why though.

Comment: Maybe `&` doesn't work with python, is it in the official documentation?

Comment: I found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators. This states, that after first statement is `False` with bitwise `&`, the second one is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(choice>=1&choice<=4):
```

This does not do what you think. Due to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) `&` is more sticky than comparison therefore above is equivalent to

```
if(choice>=(1&choice)<=4):
```

If you want to keep `&` you need to add brackets as follows

```
if((choice>=1)&(choice<=4)):
```

However note that thanks to one of python's feature you might write

```
if(1<=choice<=4):
```

to get same result