# How does Python's or operator work with None types?

Tags: python-3.x, operators, logical-operators

I was doing leetcode questions for linked lists in python 3, and the class for ListNodes is defined as follows:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

So I have this code:

```
a = ListNode(5)
if a.next is None or a.next.next is None:
    print("Test")
```

Which works fine. However, if I reorder the expressions in the `or` expression, it throws an error. This makes sense to me, as we are trying to get the `next` value of a `None` type, which does not exist.

However, we also reference `a.next.next` in the original expression. My first thought is that python evaluates the first expression (`a.next is None`), evaluates it to true, sees the `or` operator, and knows that since the first expression is `True`, the rest of the or statement can be ignored. Am I correct in this thinking? Also, does this have a name, and if so, is it used in other programming languages? From what I remember, this isn't how logic works in c/c++, so this same code block would throw an error in those languages. Am I wrong?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if a similar question has been posted before.

Comment: Try adding parenthesis around each or condition (turn it into `if (a.next is None) or (a.next.next is None):` ).

Answer (score 2):

> How does Python's or operator work with None types?

**None** is interpreted as false.

```py
print(a.next) # None
print(a.next or False) # False
print(a.next or True) # True
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans):

In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: False, **None**, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets).

The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

> However, if I reorder the expressions in the or expression, it throws an error.

```py
if a.next is None or a.next.next is None
```

**or** here is [logical OR or disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

I suspect you have changed the expression with the `|` operator ([bitwise inclusive OR](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types)).

```py
if a.next is None | a.next.next is None
```

If you change the expression with **|** operator, then you get the error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    if a.next is None | a.next.next is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

You can check this discussion to dive into the specifics of Python:
[Boolean operators vs Bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators)

> My first thought is that python evaluates the first expression (a.next
> is None), evaluates it to true, sees the or operator, and knows that
> since the first expression is True, the rest of the or statement can
> be ignored.

It's right. See [Boolean Operations in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

> Also, does this have a name, and if so, is it used in other
> programming languages?

This is called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

[Python **or**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is false.

Comment: Great explanation and thanks for the resources! This clarified the topic for me, thanks for introducing me to some new vocabulary :)