# Remove all alphanumeric words from a string using pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column with strings that look like

> '2fvRE-Ku89lkRVJ44QQFN          ABACUS LABS, INC'

and I want to convert it to look like

> 'ABACUS LABS, INC'.

My piece code :

```
list1 = data_df['Vendor'].str.split()
print(list1)
excludeList = list()
for y in list1:
    if (any([x for x in y if x.isalpha()]) and any([x for x in y if x.isdigit()])) :
      excludeList.append(y)
    if y.isdigit() or len(y) == 1:
      excludeList.append(y)
resList = [x for x in list1 if x not in excludeList]
print(restList)
```

It however gives me an error for

> 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Can anyone help me how I can remove the alphanumeric words from the string and only retain the text part in my pandas dataframe column?

Comment: please share a subset of data as well.

Comment: Edited my solution with a simplified version.  Still adhering to your logics of testing without alpha and digits in words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
data_df = pd.DataFrame({'Vendor': ['2fvRE-Ku89lkRVJ44QQFN ABACUS LABS, INC', 'abc123 CAT LABS, INC']})
data_df['Vendor'].str.replace(r'^(?:[A-Za-z-]+\d|[\d-]+[A-Za-z])[\w-]*\s*', '', regex=True)
# => 0    ABACUS LABS, INC
#    1       CAT LABS, INC
#    Name: Vendor, dtype: object
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j5NL3r/1).

*Regex details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[A-Za-z-]+\d|[\d-]+[A-Za-z])` - either one or more letters/dashes and then a digit or a one or more digits/dashes and then a letter
- `[\w-]*` - zero or more word or `-` chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions to ensure quick and elegant solution:

```
df2 = df['Text'].str.findall(r'((?<=\s)[a-zA-Z,]+(?=\s|$))').agg(' '.join)
```

Let's break it down:

1. [Regular expression](https://pythex.org/?regex=((%3F%3C%3D%5Cs)%5Ba-zA-Z%2C%5D%2B(%3F%3D%5Cs%7C%24))&test_string=2fvRE-Ku89lkRVJ44QQFN%20ABACUS%202fvRE%20LABS%2C%20INC&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) that picks up only the words without digits.
2. Per each value of `df['Text']` extract list of matches of the regex.
3. Aggregate each list using `' '.join` function that concatenates the values in the list adding space in-between.

The regex is doing this:

- to catch only "words" that are either at the beginning/end of the string there have to be used non-capturing lookbehind and lookaheads (before and after the letter catching group respectively).
- lookahead will also stop at end of the string (instead of any white char).
- the characters accepted in the "words" are defined as `[a-zA-Z,]` which allows letters lowercase and uppercase as well as a comma.

##### Performance

Comparing with @SeaBean solution the time difference on my machine is notable (per 2 million records dataframe):

- mine: 6.6522 s
- SeaBean's: 25.1773 s (3.79x slower)

There is also smaller memory impact of my solution vs. SeaBean's as he is creating additional temporary dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have column `Text` in dataframe `df`, you can try:

```
df2 = df['Text'].str.split().explode()
m = df2.str.contains(r'[A-Za-z]') & df2.str.contains(r'\d')
df_out = df2[~m].groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
df_out = df_out.to_frame(name='Text')
```

**Explanation**

We split the text into separate words then explode the list of words into multiple rows with one word in one row.  Then we test whether the word contains any alpha character(s) and digit(s) by regex by using `.str.contains()` as follows:

```
.str.contains(r'[A-Za-z]')     # test any character in [A-Za-z] in string
```

and

```
.str.contains(r'\d')           # test any numeric digit in string
```

Then with the boolean mask `m` of the alpha and digit tests, we select only those row entries that does not contains **both** the alpha and digits by:

```
df2[~m]
```

Then, we assemble the filtered words (without alphanumeric words) back to a sentence by using

```
groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
```

Here, we group by `level=0` which is the original row index before explode (i.e. original row number).

---

**Demo**

```
data = {'Text': ['2fvRE-Ku89lkRVJ44QQFN ABACUS LABS, INC', 'abc123 CAT LABS, INC']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

                                     Text
0  2fvRE-Ku89lkRVJ44QQFN ABACUS LABS, INC
1                    abc123 CAT LABS, INC


df2 = df['Text'].str.split().explode()
m = df2.str.contains(r'[A-Za-z]') & df2.str.contains(r'\d') 
df_out = df2[~m].groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
df_out = df_out.to_frame(name='Text')


               Text
0  ABACUS LABS, INC
1     CAT LABS, INC
```

### Edit

We can also simplify it as:

```
df2 = df['Text'].str.findall(r'\b(?!.*[A-Za-z]+.*\d+)(?!.*\d+.*[A-Za-z]+.*).+\b').str.join(' ').str.strip()
```

**Explanation**

Here the regex we use is still to adhere to the requirement of excluding alphanumeric word.  Regex:

```
r'\b(?!.*[A-Za-z]+.*\d+)(?!.*\d+.*[A-Za-z]+.*).+\b'
```

Within the word boundary `\b` .... `\b`, we use 2 negative lookaheads to check against **both** alpha and numeric characters.  We need 2 negative lookaheads instead of one because it is possible the alpha can appear before the digit or vice versa.

Comment: `&` is a binary and operator; it is advised to use `and` for 'boolean and'. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators).

Comment: @sophros  Unluckily your reference link is for Python, not Pandas.   For Pandas boolean mask, we need `&` rather than `and`.  Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358361/15070697)

Comment: ...interesting. You learn something every day... Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @PushpaGadde  Pleased to help!  Let me know if any further clarification needed.