# How can I test functions with parameters in Python with unittest

Tags: python, testing

I am trying to make some tests with my current code but I am struggling with the assertTrue and assertFalse as I cannot pass any test or I get numerous errors during the tests in Python.
So basically, most of my functions are something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_csv_pandas(file_path, column_name):

  if not isinstance(column_name, str) & (file_path, str):
      return False
  else:
    start = time.time()
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, ';')
    print("Listof values:", df[column_name].tolist())
    end = time.time()  
    n_lines_pandas = df.shape[0]  
    total_time = end - start 
    return total_time, n_lines_pandas
```

This is my test code so far:

```
class TestIsDottedQad(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_read_csv_pandas(self):
    self.assertTrue(read_csv_pandas("data/artists_norm.csv", 'name'))
    self.assertFalse(read_csv_pandas("data/albums_norm.csv", 235))
```

How can I set my code to make my test pass?

I tried also to use `if not isinstance(column_name, str) & (file_path, str): return value else: ...` but nothing happened.

If there is a simple way to assertTrue/False I would also like to hear about it!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't know the test, we don't know the actual function, and we  don't know what is `isinstance(foo,bar)... blah blah`.

Comment: The `&` in your `if` is not the right code. You probably want `and`. See [Boolean operators vs Bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3845018/2745495). And you probably want to also use `isinstance` on the `file_path` check, as in `isinstance(file_path, str)`.

Comment: That was it Gino, now it is perfect. Thank you! I had to use the `and` and the `isinstance(file_path, str)` as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Your `isinstance` check is incorrect. As @gino-mempin wrote, `&` is not used for boolean operations. Use `and` instead. See the following code:

```
if not (isinstance(column_name, str) and isinstance(file_path, str)):
```