# How to give multiple conditions in pyspark dataframe filter?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have to apply a filter with multiple conditions using OR on a pyspark dataframe.

I am trying to create a separate dataframe. Date value must be less than max_date or Date must be None.

How to do it?

I tried below 3 options but they all failed.

```
df.filter(df['Date'] < max_date or df['Date'] == None).createOrReplaceTempView("Final_dataset")

final_df = df.filter(df['Date'] != max_date | df['Date'] is None)

final_df = df.filter(df['Date'] != max_date or df['Date'] is None)
```

Comment: `df.filter((df['Date'] < max_date) | df['Date'].isNull())`

Answer (score 1):

```
final_df = df.filter((df.Date < max_date) | (df.Date.isNull()))
```

Regular logical python operators don't work in Pyspark conditions; you need to use bitwise operators. They can also be a bit tricky so you might need extra parenthesis to disambiguate the expression.

Have a look here:
[Boolean operators vs Bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators/25949622)