# python loc TypeError bitwise_and not supported

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, algorithmic-trading

I have a data frame with float values and now that I'm trying to use `loc`, it returns the error below:

```
 result = op(x, y)
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Peyman\Desktop\pythonProject1\huge_scale_backtest_of_intraday_cryptocurrency_data_using_python_&_sql_(1).py", line 141, in <module>
    daily.loc[(daily['Low'].shift(-7))>daily['Close_DAILY'] & (daily['Close_DAILY'])>(daily['SMA200']), 'Buy']='YES'
```

The code line that is causing the error is :

```
daily.loc[(daily['Low'].shift(-7))>daily['Close_DAILY'] & (daily['Close_DAILY']>daily['SMA200']), 'Buy']='YES'
```

my data frame is created by the function below:

```
def getdailydata(symbol):
frame = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol,Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY, '400 days ago UTC'))
frame = frame.iloc[:, :5]
frame.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close_DAILY']
frame[['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close_DAILY']] = frame[['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close_DAILY']].astype(float)

frame.Date = pd.to_datetime(frame.Date, unit='ms')

return frame
```

and `daily['SMA200']` is created by the line below:

```
daily['SMA200'] = daily['Close_DAILY'].rolling(window=200).mean()
```

Comment: you need to provide a minimal reproducible data/code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boolean operators vs Bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators)