# In Julia when to use `!` (boolean not) vs `~` (bitwise not)?

Tags: julia, boolean-logic

The docs say that `!` is "Boolean not. Implements three-valued logic" and `~` is "Bitwise not."

When should one be used versus the other?

There is a [similar question for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845018/boolean-operators-vs-bitwise-operators) about comparison operators, but I am not sure where the languages may differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, `!` is boolean not and `~` is bitwise not. This ends up being a bit redundant since bitwise not for booleans is just boolean not so anywhere you can use `!` you should also be able to use `~`. (This is always true with standard Julia should remain true as long as package don't addg methods that don't conform to the intended meaning of these operators.) So if you're a Matlab programmer, for example, and you're used to using `~` for boolean not, then you can keep doing that. My suggestion, however, would be to be as precise in your meaning as you can be: if you expect the argument to be boolean, use `!` so that you get an error if it isn't. Use `~` if you expect the argument to be an integer and want to flip its bits. But frankly it's no big deal to use `~` for booleans. If it really matters that the argument is boolean, like if it's being used in a conditional, then the error will show up soon anyway.

There was a discussion in the lead up to the 1.0 release about removing `!` from the language and using `~` for boolean negation instead, but we ended up keeping `!` because it's familiar from languages like C and C++ and giving it any other meaning would be actively confusing. But it's telling that removing it was an option in the first place.